# Android: Exception in the creation of a ContextMenu

Tags: android

I'm trying to "go", after clicking in an ActionBar menu option, to a **floating contextMenu**. But I can't even load the app because before launch it I get an exception.
I'm trying to do it with this simple code:

**indexActivity.java**

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
            registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.action_share));
(...)
```

then I have the

```
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
(...)
```

**menu.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".IndexActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
```

But I'm getting Exception and I can't understand why since I have the 
`setContentView` before `findViewById(R.id.action_share). Can you please help me?`

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.converter.android.converter/com.converter.android.converter.IndexActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference
            at com.converter.android.converter.IndexActivity.onCreate(IndexActivity.java:33)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the registerForContextMenu?

Comment: @ user2875404, Yes...commenting it I have no exception...but in that case I can not create the context menu..

Comment: sure.. a workaround would be to make this thing a button and call onCreateContextMenu() from there. Not the best way, but actually this is what I always did haha

Comment: can you post the xml layout file too ?

Comment: @mt0s what is suppose layout.xml have related to this issue? It's because I didn't make any change there related to this. I have only changed the menu.xml adding the new item (I have update this post with the menu.xml)  and the java file.

Comment: action_share isn't displayed on actionbar since app:showAsAction="never". Try changing it to app:showAsAction="always" .

Comment: The problem persists..